# Disable Content Security Policy in PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, content-security-policy

I am trying to use a WebSocket in a `page.evaulate()` call in PhantomJS (2.1.1).  When trying to connect to the WebSocket server, I get the following error:

`SecurityError: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent.`

I was able to disable the CSP in Firefox by going to `about:config` and setting `security.csp.enable` to false.  After doing this, I could run the same code from the PhantomJS script by pasting it into the console in Firefox with no problems.

Is it possible to disable Content Security Policy in PhantomJS?  (I have tried setting `page.webSecurityEnabled = false` and `page.localToRemoteUrlAccessEnabled = true` to no avail.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PhantomJS latest stable version 2.1.1 has a bug when it tries to get a webpage that has the following response header:
content-security-policy: default-src 'none'

The Fix:
Branch 2.1.1, **File: \phantomjs\src\qt\qtwebkit\Source\WebCore\page\ContentSecurityPolicy.cpp**, Change line 354:

`, m_allowEval(false)`

To:

`, m_allowEval(true)`

Then build.py -r ... Enjoy!

Comment: Not a solution for me as I don't have root on the server and there are no compilers on it, so forced to use installed package for PhantomJS. If there's no way to change this in a config file or in a script, there really should be.

Comment: Since asking this question, I've redone the script in question using Selenium webdriver. I'll have to take some time and test this, and I'll mark it as an accepted answer if it works - thank you!